# Middleware for Laravel API call works in browser but not curl

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, curl, middleware

so I am building an API in Laravel and I created custom middleware to authenticate the user based on their username and password either as part of authorization header or by passing the credentials in as part of the query string.

Example:

```
curl http://myapi.com/api/v1/getsomething -u username:password
```

-- or --

```
curl http://myapi.com/api/v1/getsomething?username=username&password=password
```

Both methods worh in the browser as expected, but when I try and run these via curl in the terminal, my middleware is not being hit during the request. Is there any reason why this may be?

Comment: what is the curl feedback ?

Comment: "[1] 27303" then goes back to command prompt